# Can you use escape sequences to change color of tmux status bar?

Tags: tmux

There are times when it is convenient to modify the title in the tmux status bar using terminal escape sequences (eg `printf '\033k%s\033\' "$title"`).  Is it possible to change the color of the status bar in the same way?

Comment: More convenient than `tmux set-option status-style "bg=blue"`?

Comment: @chepner The use case case is having an interactive shell on a remote host change the window title of the local tmux window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use styles in #[] --- https://man.openbsd.org/tmux.1#STYLES